# Switch con cin.rdstate()

Tags: c++

Estoy leyendo un libro de programación que afirma lo siguiente:

> La función miembro **rdstate** devuelve el estado de error del flujo. Por ejemplo, una llamada a `cin.rdstate()`
>   devolvería el estado del flujo, que entonces se podría evaluar mediante una instrucción **switch** que examine los *bits* *eofbit*, *badbit*, *failbit* y *goodbit*.

¿Cómo funciona entonces la función `cin.rdstate()`?
¿Cómo se implementa la instrucción **switch** mencionada en el texto?

Answer (score 0):

> - ¿ Cómo funciona entonces la función `cin.rdstate( )` ?

En la documentación tienes la repuesta:

> #### `iostate rdstate( ) const;`
>
> Returns the current stream error state.
>   **Parameters**
>   (none)
>   **Return value**
>   current stream error state. It is a bitmask type and can be a combination of the following constants:
>   `goodbit` -> no error
>   `badbit` -> irrecoverable stream error
>   `failbit` -> input/output operation failed (formatting or extraction error)
>   `eofbit` -> associated input sequence has reached end-of-file

Devuelve un valor, el cual puede ser un valor individual, o una combinación binaria de varios ( usando `&` ).

> - ¿ Cómo se implementa la instrucción `switch` mencionada en el texto ?

Los `switch( )` **necesitan** expresiones `constexpr` en sus etiquetas `case`, así que utilizarlos para determinar la presencia de uno o varios bits activos es, cuanto menos, **poco práctico**: hay que indicar todas las posibles combinaciones. Por suerte para nosotros, **no todas** se pueden dar a la vez, tal como se muestra en esta tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
<sub>Tomada de aquí: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate</sub>

Con lo que nuestro `switch( )` quedaría tal que así:

```
switch( std::cout.rdstate( ) ) {
case std::ios_base::badbit:
  ...
case std::ios_base::failbit:
  ...
case std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::badbit:
  ...
case std::ios_base::eofbit:
  ...
case std::ios_base::eofbit | std::ios_base::badbit:
  ...
case std::ios_base::eofbit | std::ios_base::failbit:
  ...
case std::ios_base::eofbit | std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::badbit:
  ...
default: // goodbit
  ...
}
```

Afortunamdamente, según vimos en la documentación, podemos agrupar los distintos `case` por *grupos* o *prioridades*, lo que simplifica un poco:

```
switch( std::cout.rdstate( ) ) {
case std::ios_base::badbit:
case std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::badbit:
case std::ios_base::eofbit | std::ios_base::badbit:
case std::ios_base::eofbit | std::ios_base::failbit | std::ios_base::badbit:
  // badbit. Errores irrecuperables.
  ...
case std::ios_base::failbit:
case std::ios_base::eofbit | std::ios_base::failbit:
  // failbit. Error de formato.
  ...
case std::ios_base::eofbit:
  // Fin de archivo.
  ...
default: // goodbit
  ...
}
```

Personalmente, opinio que unos cuantos `if( ) ... else ...` quedan mas legibles:

```
auto state = stream.rdstate( );

if( state & std::ios_base::badbit ) {
  // Errores irrecuperables.
  ...
} else if( state & std::ios_base::failbit ) {
  // Errores de formato.
  ...
} else if( state & std::ios_base::eofbit ) {
  // Fin de archivo.
  ...
} else {
  // Todo Ok.
}
```